# Factorize: $a^3(b+c)+b^3(a+c)+c^3(a+b)$.

Tags: factoring

Factorize: $a^3(b+c)+b^3(a+c)+c^3(a+b)$.

I found this question on a high school textbook but it seems impossible to be further factorized. The best I can get is:

$a^3(b+c)+b^3(a+c)+c^3(a+b) = (a+b+c)(a^3+b^3+c^3)-a^4-b^4-c^4$.

Since this question is from a high school textbook, I assume the field that we are working on is $\mathbb{R}$. We can not further factorize $a^4+b^4+c^4$ so there is no common factor with the previous term. Thus this can not be further factorized.

I am wondering if my conclusion is correct or not. I am also curious if we can factorize it on a bigger field. Please help.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha doesn't return a factorisation.

Comment: I get $(a^2+b^2+c^2)(ab+bc+ca)-abc~(a+b+c)$.

Comment: Also, $(a+b+c)^2=(a^2+b^2+c^2)+2~(ab+bc+ca).~$ Perhaps Vieta's relations will help ?

Comment: @Lucian. No luck so far following your path. Vieta's relations does not help either.

Comment: It might be a good idea to provide a reference for the textbook where you found this question.

Comment: You surely can factorize it over $\mathbb{C}$, in three different ways at least. Just write it as a cubic equation $$(b+c)a^3+(b^3+c^3)a+bc(b^2+c^2)=0$$ and solve

Comment: Wolfram Alpha says that the polynomial is irreducible. So .....